# Adding/Overriding Webpack Loaders for a create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

is there an option to add a loader for a certain file type to a boilerplate create-react-app application? Whatever I tried, I don't seem to be able to get it working without specifying the loader itself in the js file with:

```
!!import List from './data.txt'
```

I found the following link, but am hesitant to believe that the de-facto default way of creating a react app nowadays doesn't allow to override/add loaders (simply):

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2608

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At my last project we used this:

npm i @craco/craco

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco

It allows config changes without ejecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

- in your `react-app-env.d.ts` add `declare module "*.txt"`
- then in the code you can get the content in Promise:

  ```
  import dataRaw from "./data.txt"

  fetch(dataRaw)
    .then(raw => raw.text())
    .then(text => { <here you have it> }
  ```